# Error handling practises with methods that return collections

Tags: c#, exception

If I am trying to get an element from a collection (and the value must be there), what is the best course of action? Return null?

Also, if I am trying to get an element from a collection but the value is not there (and does not strictly have to be there, ie its not fatal) what is the best course of action?

And lastly if a collection is returned from a method and that is empty, I am guessing that the best course of aciton is throw an exception if it is fatal and otherwise do not.

Thanks

Comment: You should paste some of your code...

Comment: I think the "best practice" is subjective. In our team our Data Access layers return null when an error occurs and our Business Logic Layers determine what to do (throw an exception perhaps if it is a fatal error)

Comment: No code sample as this is hypothetical but I have come across this dielmma many times. Hmm interesting advice Ulises.

Comment: Throw an exception, don't throw an exception, covered by previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally helpful to provide a pair of methods, one of which will guarantees that it will either return an item or throw, and the other of which guarantees that it may or may not return an item, but will only throw if the collection has become corrupted in some fashion (beyond the non-existence of the requested item).  Some people dislike the notion of using a parameter to indicate whether the method should throw if an item is not found.  While use of a parameter should not be the primary means of indicating which variation of the function is desired, having an overload with such such a parameter can be useful when trying to avoid duplicated code.